# Convert HTML Name Attribute to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm creating a form data serializing function that passes information via AJAX to a PHP file for error checking and parsing. I know I could technically use the `.serialize()` method in JQuery, but I need more control over my data. Basically I want to parse the fields from my form into a multidimensional Javascript object that is then converted to JSON to be sent via AJAX. I've built up a method that works for the most part, but still has some flaws. Here's my Javascript/JQuery code:

```
var formData = { };

function serializeAllFormData() {
   $(':input').not('button').each(function() {
      //This pulls the fields name for use in error message generation
      var fieldName = $(this).parent().children('label').html();

      //Takes the value of the field
      var value = $(this).val();

      //This section finds all fields that needs additional error checking like email/url
      var allClasses = $(this).attr('class');
      allClasses = allClasses.match(/special_(\w*)/);
      if (allClasses != null) {
         var special = allClasses[1];
      }
      else {
          var special = '';
      }

     //Takes the name attribute such as '[contact][email]' and makes an array of just the names. ['contact', 'email']
     var locationArray = $(this).attr('name').match(/\w+/g);

     //Making a temporary object that will be nested. This object holds all the necessary information for parsing in my errorCheck.php file.
     tempObj = { };
     tempObj[0] = value;
     tempObj[1] = fieldName;
     tempObj[2] = $(this).attr('name');
     tempObj[3] = special;

     //Iterate through, starting with the smallest child of the name attribute and working backwards, nesting the objects
     var length = locationArray.length;
     for (i = length; i > 0; i--) {
         locationName = locationArray[i-1];
         if (i > 1) {
            var tempObj2 = { };
            tempObj2[locationName] = tempObj;
            tempObj = tempObj2;
        }

        //For the last iteration, nest the object in the formData variable itself
        if (i == 1) {
            formData[locationName] = tempObj;
        }
    }
});
   formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
   return formData;
}
```

So it works great if it's just running in one dimension. i.e. the name attribute is simple like `name="[email]"` or `name="[phone_number]"`. However once it gets to more complex, multidimensional fields, the formData object only keeps the last field. The formData object gets overwritten during each iteration. An example would be if I have this HTML structure:

```
<div><label>Email</label><input type="text" name="[contact][email]" /></div>
<div><label>Phone Number</label><input type="text" name="[contact][phone]" /></div>
```

If I run the method, the general structure would look like this: `Object (contact => Object (phone => Object (0 => "", 1 => "Phone Number", 2 => "[contact][phone]", 3 => "")))`

So I need a way to make sure that existing objects within the formData don't get overwritten on each iteration.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If i understood you correctly (based from the title of your question) you trying to represent name attribute as an object? if, so why don't use `element.getAttributeNode("name");`? and if you want some custom type attribute use `data-myattr=""` http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: I would use that approach but all the `element.getAttributeNode('name');` returns is a string. I need an object that can be converted to JSON so it is navigable when it is decoded by the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correctly initialize your temporary variables. Ex:

```
var tempObj = [];
```

As it is right now you are actually creating global variables which are been reused through each iteration.

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't help. I think I'm going in the wrong order is the problem. I'm trying to start from the top now and iterate to the bottom rather than bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research, I determined that it isn't possible to do exactly what I want using Javascript, so I created a workaround. I edited the code above so that the index key for each field is simply the whole name attribute itself. So for example if the name attribute was `[contact][email]` then the resulting object would look like this `Object => ('[contact][email]' => Object (0 => '', 1 => 'Email', 2 => '[contact][email]', 3 => ''))`. Then, once that objected is converted to JSON, I pass it via AJAX to my PHP file. Once in the PHP file, I run the following code to convert it into a multi-dimensional array:

PHP

```
$multiDimensional = array();

foreach ($formData as $key => $field) {
    preg_match_all('/\w+/', $key, $keyArray);
    $keyArray = $keyArray[0];
    $length = count($keyArray);
    switch ($length) {
       case 1:
           $multiDimensional{$keyArray[0]} = $field;
           break;
       case 2:
           $multiDimensional{$keyArray[0]}{$keyArray[1]} = $field;
           break;
       case 3:
           $multiDimensional{$keyArray[0]}{$keyArray[1]}{$keyArray[2]} = $field;
           break;
       case 4:
           $multiDimensional{$keyArray[0]}{$keyArray[1]}{$keyArray[2]}{$keyArray[3]} = $field;
           break;
       case 5:
           $multiDimensional{$keyArray[0]}{$keyArray[1]}{$keyArray[2]}{$keyArray[3]}{$keyArray[4]} = $field;
           break;
   }
}
```

It's a little bulky but it works. `$multiDimensional` ends up with a structure that follows the structure of the HTML name attribute. If anyone knows how to do a similar thing in Javascript however, I'd love to hear it!